Does the general form of this integral exist?
I'm working on some analysis (for fun) and have come across this integral. I would like to know if there is a general solution.
$$ \int \frac{x \, f'(x)}{\alpha + \beta \, f(x)} \; dx $$
Where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are real, positive constants.
I've done some work on my own, and it seems like I may be out of luck. But I'd like to have a second opinion to know for sure. I tried using Mathematica and Sympy, both of which found no solutions in the form of elementary functions. As these both use the Risch algorithm (or a variant), it would seem that any solution (should it exist) must be composed of special/exotic functions.
I made a bit of progress (if it could be called that) by applying Integration By Parts (IBP) with the choice $u=x$ and $dv = \frac{f'(x)}{\alpha + \beta \, f(x)}$.
$$ \int \frac{x \, f'(x)}{\alpha + \beta \, f(x)} \; dx = x \, \ln(\alpha + \beta \, f(x)) - \int \ln(\alpha + \beta \, f(x)) \; dx $$
It seems to me that the remaining integral has no closed form, but I'm not certain. I was hoping that it may be related to the logarithmic integral function, but I'm not seeing a clear connection.
There is no reason why this integral shouldn't be computed numerically. In fact, it usually is in this particular application. I'm just trying to find some analytical solutions for benchmarking. Again, this is for fun, so I really appreciate anyone weighing in.
Thank you!
